# backbone.js IE8 appendChild() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, cross-browser

Typical 'works in Chrome/FF but not IE' story. IE9 seems to handle it fine though.

The only thing that appears in the IE console is: 
*SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.*
*jquery.min.js, line 3 character 32461*

Here's [screenshot](http://draconianbuilder.com/images/IE_dies_on_render_call.png) of the IE Profiler tracing the error.

And here is the code from my Nav.js file:

```
    // Build nav menu array
    var navLinks =  [ {"style" : "home"         ,"page" : ""                    ,"name" : "Home"                ,"tier" : 1     ,"icon" : "home"}, 
              {"style" : "job-trans"    ,"page" : "view/jobTransaction" ,"name" : "Job Transactions"    ,"tier" : 1     ,"icon" : "barcode"},
              {"style" : "job"          ,"page" : "view/job"            ,"name" : "Jobs"                ,"tier" : 1     ,"icon" : "inbox"},
              {"style" : "user"         ,"page" : "view/user"           ,"name" : "Users"               ,"tier" : 1     ,"icon" : "user"},
              {"style" : "report"       ,"page" : "page/report"         ,"name" : "Reports"             ,"tier" : 2},// ,"icon" : "signal"},
              {"style" : "customer"     ,"page" : "view/customer"       ,"name" : "Customers"           ,"tier" : 2}
            ];

    var jobSearchAttr = $.browser.msie ? "value=\"Enter Job #\" data-browser=\"IE\" style=\"font-size: 16px\"" : "placeholder=\"Enter Job #\"";
    var userSearchAttr = $.browser.msie ? "value=\"Enter User ID\" data-browser=\"IE\" style=\"font-size: 16px; padding-left:0;\"" : "placeholder=\"Enter User ID\"";

    // Sort array elements into buttons and dropdowns with appropriate elements
    var i, t1LinkArray = [], t2LinkArray = [], t2ClassArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        switch(navLinks[i]["tier"]) {
            case 1:
                t1LinkArray.push( "<li class=\"" + navLinks[i]['style'] + "\"><a href=\"#/" + navLinks[i]['page'] + "\"><i class=\"icon-" + navLinks[i]['icon'] + " icon-white\"></i> " + navLinks[i]['name'] + "</a></li>" );
                break;
            case 3:
                t2LinkArray.push( "<li class=\"" + navLinks[i]['style'] + "\"><a href=\"#/" + navLinks[i]['page'] + "\">" + navLinks[i]['name'] + "</a></li>" );
                t2ClassArray.push( navLinks[i]['style'] );
                break;
        }
    }

    // Create Navbar View
    NavView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Define View template
        template: _.template( $('#navbarTemplate').html() ),

        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            // Call the template and pass data object
            this.$el.html( this.template({ t1LinkArray : t1LinkArray, t2LinkArray : t2LinkArray, t2ClassArray : t2ClassArray }) );
        },

    });
    var nav = new NavView({ el:$('nav') });
```

At a loss as to why this is crashing only in IE 7/8.

**EDIT** :: Here is the template, as currently embedded below the body.

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="clear: both;">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">

              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>

              <p class="navbar-text pull-right"><a class="brand" href="/workflow3"><em>Brand</em></a></p>

              <div class="nav-collapse pull-left">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <!-- List Tier 1 pages -->
                  {{ t1LinkArray.join("\n") }}

                  <!-- Style dropdown with each child's page class -->
                  <li class="dropdown {{ t2ClassArray.join(" ") }}"> 

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <!--  List Tier 2 pages -->
                      {{ t2LinkArray.join("\n") }}
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>

              </div> <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div> <!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </div> <!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div> <!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: What does your template code look like?

Comment: See the edit for template code.

Comment: I'm assuming that "#navbarTemplate" is the id on the script that contains this template? Since it's not in the HTML you provided...

Comment: BTW, I did a little searching on this issue, and came across something that intrigued me and that was someone got the same error with the minified version of jquery and it went away when they went to the raw. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, #navbarTemplate is the ID, the syntax highlighting wasn't enjoying the script tags though. ;) .. I had not heard of the minified version causing an issue, I'll try that in the morning and see if it clears things up. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately, using the uncompressed jQuery lib does not seem to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I still have not found a solution to the actual problem at hand here. Technically this doesn't even count as a work around, but it does create a working environment!

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

Obvious advantage, no longer have to pander to IE's idiosyncrasies.

I hate not knowing what's causing this though, so anyone else, please feel free to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but i was getting this error today, and this was the top result so still relevant i guess.

You were using html5 data-attributes in your markup - presumably your document was html5?  If you used any of the new tags unsupported by IE8 (without adding a shim of some description) jQuery produces this error. Try this in the head of your page.

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Other than that it apparently tends to turn up in malformed html - eg. if you've forgotten to close a tag or missed a closing quote in an attribute.

Comment: I missed this reply months back when it came in, but wanting to figure out the why I went back and looked. Thought I had included the shiv out of hand and sure enough...
<script src="lib/html5shiv-updated-min.js"></script>

Malformed html is still a possibility though, very hard to diagnose with so many things in templates though. I'll have to go back through this when I have some time.

Answer (score 1):

I just helped a coworker troubleshoot this issue in IE8 today. We discovered he was attempting to append to an element that cannot have children (in his case, an IMG tag).

I noticed the jQuery selector on `new NavView({ el:$('nav') });` should be **.nav** There is no `nav` tag (at least in your code sample) and so it's trying to add nodes to a non-existent element.

Comment: You are correct, I did not include the html in my examples. It does reference <nav></nav> in my index.html file though. (I had to go back and look to make sure though.)

Given the replies I've seen so far there's a chance I'm just missing a closing tag somewhere. I'll look when I have some time. Thanks for the heads up though, I hope it helps those who come looking.